# Why is this Python 3 asyncio client sending the bytes only after the Python process is interrupted?

Tags: python, client-server, python-3.4, python-asyncio

Why is my client timing out at code line:

`response = yield from asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(), timeout=3.0)`

instead of getting a message back?

The server piece only registers it got a message from this client after the client times out and I actually issue a `ctrl + d` to kill the Python interpreter

---

### client.py

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def test_connection(host, port):
    # Get the streams for the socket
    print('Starting client connection')
    reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection(host, port)

    message = 'Test Message'.encode('ascii')

    # Start communication
    print('Sending message to {}:{} - {}'.format(host, port, message))
    writer.write(message)

    print('Waiting 3 sec for response...')
    response = yield from asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(), timeout=3.0)
    print('Got response: {}'.format(response.decode('ascii')))

    writer.close()


def run():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = asyncio.async(test_connection())
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that you're calling `reader.read()` on the server-side (and also on the client-side), which will block until an `EOF` is sent from the server. But presumably you're not doing that - you're just sending some bytes over and keeping the connection open.

Instead, you need either to call `readline()` and make sure to append `b'\n'` to your mess payloads, call `read` with some size to limit the number of bytes you wait for, or call [`writer.write_eof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamWriter.write_eof) after writing your message payload, assuming you don't plan to use the `writer` anymore. Using `readline()` or `write_eof` are probably your safest options. Here's a complete example demonstrating using `readline()`:

## client.py

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def test_connection(host, port):
    # Get the streams for the socket
    print('Starting client connection')
    reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection(host, port)

    message = 'Test Message\n'.encode('ascii')

    # Start communication
    print('Sending message to {}:{} - {}'.format(host, port, message))
    writer.write(message)

    print('Waiting 3 sec for response...')
    response = yield from asyncio.wait_for(reader.readline(), timeout=5.0)
    print('Got response: {}'.format(response.decode('ascii')))

    writer.close()


def run():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = asyncio.async(test_connection('localhost', 5000))
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
    loop.close()

run()
```

## server.py

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def got_connection(reader, writer):
    msg = yield from reader.readline()
    message = 'another Test Message\n'.encode('ascii')
    print('Sending message to {}:{} - {}'.format('localhost', 5000, message))
    writer.write(message)


def run():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    server = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.start_server(
                                        got_connection, 'localhost', 5000))
    loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
    loop.close()

run()
```

And here are the changes to use `write_eof()`:

## client.py

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def test_connection(host, port):
    # Get the streams for the socket
    print('Starting client connection')
    reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection(host, port)

    message = 'Test Message'.encode('ascii')

    # Start communication
    print('Sending message to {}:{} - {}'.format(host, port, message))
    writer.write(message)
    writer.write_eof()

    print('Waiting 3 sec for response...')
    response = yield from asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(), timeout=5.0)
    print('Got response: {}'.format(response.decode('ascii')))

    writer.close()
```

## server.py

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def got_connection(reader, writer):
    msg = yield from reader.read()
    message = 'another Test Message'.encode('ascii')
    print('Sending message to {}:{} - {}'.format('localhost', 5000, message))
    writer.write(message)
    writer.write_eof()
```